# How to use .editorconfig for code formatting in git pre-commit hook?

Tags: git, githooks, code-formatting, pre-commit-hook, editorconfig

In my project there is a requirement to check for code formatting errors. This needs to happen during a git commit. I want to make use of the `pre-commit` hook but the catch here is the format validation needs to be performed using the rules mentioned in `.editorconfig` file, which is already present in the project repository.

Please do suggest a way to use `.editorcofig` in git `pre-commit` hook.

Comment: I would guess the requirement is that the code needs to be formatted according to the `.editorconfig` as it is found in the commit. I.e if you want to change the formatting you have to change the code and `.editorconfig` in the same commit. Is that the case?

Comment: Oh, and could you post the command to manually check the formatting of the code?

Comment: @SebDieBln I don't know if there is any command for that. In case we have a command to run rules in .editorconfig against file(s), that would be straight forward to add the same command in pre-commit hook.

Comment: @SebDieBln if you want to change the formatting you have to change the code and .editorconfig in the same commit. Is that the case? 
- Yes

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be [a tool which can check code](https://github.com/editorconfig-checker/editorconfig-checker) for conformance to an `.editorconfig` file.  There are probably others; this is just the first one I found in a search.

However, I should point out that [the Git FAQ notes that `pre-commit` hooks can be bypassed](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks) trivially with `--no-verify` without anyone being able to notice.  As a result, while they can be helpful for developers who want to use them, they aren't an effective control, and you'll need to use a CI system (or, if possible, a pre-receive hook) on the server side to prevent bypassing them.

Comment: I tried this `editorconfig-checker` as well. But looks like it uses some predefined rules, not the ones defined in `.editorconfig` in project repository. May be I will try [Mega-Linter](https://megalinter.github.io/latest/) once again as mentioned in README file.

Comment: Looks like this `mega-linter` does the work as part of CI, which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this [Vamsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10503545/vamsi-vegesna)?